# USB Tethering Problem

Tags: windows, usb-tethering

I am using `USB Tethering` to use my phone as a modem. Whenever I activate `USB Tethering`, there will be two network present in my PC. One named `Network X`(X being a number which is incremented every time I connect. Currently it's 13.), another named `unidentified network`. On basic Network section, it would show multiple network and there is no access to internet.

To use internet, I have to disable `Local Area Connection 9` and then enable it which removes the `unidentified network`. Now I can use internet. I have do it every time I want to use Tethering.

My Handset: Sony Xperia Tipo

Android OS: Ice Cream Sandwich

PC OS: Windows 7

What is the cause of this and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you doing USB tethering? Using an app? (or the phone's default feature? -- I don't know where this is though)

Comment: I'm using the default one.